# Update single event from recursive event using microsoft graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

Is it possible to update a single event from a recursive event using Microsoft Graph API? if it is possible to update, please share a useful link.

I tried finding it in the official documentation but couldnt find how to change time of a single instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the id of recursive event (master series event id) and use it to get all event instances in specified time range

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{master_series_event_id}/instances?startDateTime=2023-04-17T09:00:00.0000000&endDateTime=2023-04-20T09:00:00.0000000
```

Find the event id of specific single instance and call the following endpoint to change the time

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events/{instance_event_id}
{
    "start": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-18T11:15:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    },
    "end": {
        "dateTime": "2023-04-18T11:45:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": "UTC"
    }
}
```

Resources:

[List event instances](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-list-instances?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

[Update event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/event-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)